# How to get the page of a rendering used in a page in search

Tags: content-search, lucene, azure-search

I have to implement `Azure` search but would like to try with Lucene first in the local setup. I am following this [example](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/) by @kamsar

1.Created the `SubcontentField` class
2.Created the `patch config` and
3.Rebuilt the index for `sitecore_web_index`

[ Did not add any custom field/template IDs in the Lucene configs. Using the default ones as it is without any changes. ]

Here is my code which is triggered, when a user clicks the search button on the page.

```
string keywords = <keywords entered by user>;    

 using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
 {
   var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()  
              .Where(x => x.Content.Contains(keywords) && 
                     x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
                    
   List<SearchResultItem> lst = query.ToList();       
 }
```

Now I search using a keyword "stories". There is a rendering on the home page, which has the title "Stories". I am expecting the Home page item in one of the result items inside `lst`.

But there are other items like controller rendering, media library, etc that have the name "stories".

I would like to get the list of page items that have the keyword used in any of the renderings for that page.

As suggested in the article, should I search in any particular field?
Could someone please guide me on how to get my desired results here?

Using sc8.2 u3 with MVC

**UPDATE:**

I did this to see if there really was home page in the returned list

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                       .Where(x => x.ItemId == SitecoreUtility.GetHomeItem().ID &&   
   x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);

List<SearchResultItem> lst = query.ToList();
string sss = lst[0].Content;
```

It did return one result, but "sss" got only one word which was "Home". So I'm doubting if the example from the article really worked for me, I mean did it really get all content fields values into one field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the "sitecore_web_index" which contains all items of web database. If you want to get just pages, you need to filter results. For example:

```
string keywords = <keywords entered by user>;    
 using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
 {
   var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()  
              .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(ID.Parse("{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}")) x.Content.Contains(keywords) && 
                     x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name)

   List<SearchResultItem> lst = query.ToList();       
 }
```

,where {0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450} is id of your home page. It means that search result will comtain all items under the item with id = {0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450} including this item itself and whose corresponds another conditions.

Comment: This overlooks a central part of the question; "I would like to get the list of page items that have the keyword used in any of the renderings for that page."

Comment: He wrote that he implemented the SubcontentField as it described by the link https://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/   which extend the _content field and content which placed in datasources of renderings are associated with indexed item.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich I tried your suggestion but it returns no result. The home page has the keyword "stories" for sure in a rendering datasource

Comment: Have you put the correct ID of your home page item?

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich Yes I did

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on a code of SubcontentField, then you need to change something in the Home item and publish it. You will be able to see what is your SubcontentField returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66885/discussion-between-artsem-prashkovich-and-qwerty).